# Election day in Rectangularea (Crack 'em, pack 'em, stack 'em, elect 'em)

Tags: dissection

Remember when Rectangularea gained parliamentary representation?

The regrettably segregated population broke down into parties as follows.
Gerrymandericans (`g`) were concentrated in 4/9 of the land
while Majoricrats (`m`) pervaded the other 5/9.

```
                                  ___________
                                 | g | m | m |
                                 |___|___|___|
                                 | g | g | m |
                                 |___|___|___|
                                 | m | g | m |
                                 |___|___|___|
```

Census results granted just 3 seats, so how to delineate constituencies?

```
   ___________                                                  ___________
  | g   m   m |                                                | g | m | m |
  |___________|                                                |   |   |   |
  | g   g   m |   ?   Or, as was hornswoggled at the time:     | g | g | m |   .
  |___________|                                                |   |   |   |
  | m   g   m |                                                | m | g | m |
  |___________|                                                |___|___|___|
 2:1 Majoricratic                                           2:1 Gerrymanderican
```

Ah politics.
Neither approach could have produced proportional representation.
Everyone was embittered and a clumsy breeding frenzy ensued.
Predictably little miscegeny produced a population more polarized than ever.

> Can you come up with a rectangular map,
>   with more `g`s than above, and even more `m`s,
>   that can be split into rectangular districts **in two different ways**,
>   one way where Gerrymandericans gain representation
>   that is reciprocal of their numbers
>   (that would be 5:4 in the case above, not 2:1 as shown)
>   and the other way where Majoricrats are *proportionally* represented
>   (that would be 5:4 in the case above, again, not 2:1)?

The resulting hypothetical constituencies
are all equally sized and all rectangular,
but not necessarily equally shaped,
and number greater than the original three.

(Note, this was witnessed by someone
 only academically acquainted with parliamentary terminology.
 Any editing to make this more realistic would be appreciated.)

Comment: Equally sized, not necessarily equally shaped, and more than 3, here comes a revision

Comment: `m` needs to be greater than `g` right?

Comment: @somebody m=g would offer trivial solutions.

Comment: You thieve! I've been toying with an idea for a puzzle about Gerrymandering and elections ever since Nov2016 (with some failed prototypes)... Oh well, need a new idea now ;c)  (+1)

Comment: Hold on to your ballot, @BmyGuest, I had hoped to come up with a truly  wiggly [`grid-deduction`](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid-deduction) puzzle but tried this out instead, after researching proposed supposedly infallible real-life solutions. I gave up on the more fun (and more effort) version you probably imagined.

Comment: @humn the problem is, that Jaab's general solution is so general, that any visually more fun puzzle does not provide a challenge anymore, just a geometrical reshuffling. I hold on to the idea as a potential sub-plot to one of my future puzzles though.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty, @humn. I hope there are still some new and interesting puzzle ideas to be explored based on these concepts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one way of doing this, though there may well be a smaller map that works.

> The map is 3x9, split into 9 regions of size 3. The voting proportions are 5:4, so there are 12 g and 15 m votes.
>
> ```
>             g g g g g m m m g
>             g g g g g m m g m
>             m m m m m m m m m
> ```
>
> Splitting into horizontal 1x3 rectangles gives 5m and 4g:
>
> ```
>             g g g   g g m   m m g
>
>             g g g   g g m   m g m
>
>             m m m   m m m   m m m
> ```
>
> Splitting into vertical 3x1 rectangles gives 4m and 5g:
>
> ```
>             g   g   g   g   g   m   m   m   g
>             g   g   g   g   g   m   m   g   m
>             m   m   m   m   m   m   m   m   m
> ```

Edit:
Here is a slightly smaller map with a larger ratio

> A 5x5 map with voting proportions 3:2, i.e. 15m and 10g.
>
> ```
>             m m g m m
>             g g g m m
>             g g g m m
>             g g m m m
>             m m m m g
> ```
>
> Split into horizontal rectangles, we get g:m :: 2:3, vertical rectangles gives g:m :: 3:2.

Edit 2:
An even smaller, simpler map:

> A 3x5 map with voting proportions 3:2, i.e. 9m and 6g.
>
> ```
>             g g m   m   m
>             g g m   m   m
>             g g m   m   m
> ```
>
> Split the square part into vertical rectangles, we get g:m :: 2:3, horizontal rectangles gives g:m :: 3:2.

Edit 3:
The construction above generalises to any ratio $m:g$ provided that $g<m<2g$.

> [image]
>
> Take a rectangle of size $m$ by $m+g$. Fill the first $g$ columns with g-votes, and the remaining $m$ columns with m-votes. Obviously, splitting this rectangle into vertical strips gives the expected outcome, since every district unanimously votes one way or the other. If the left $m\times m$ square is split into $m$ horizontal districts instead, all of them vote Gerrymanderican (since each district has size $m$, has $g$ votes for the Gerrymandericans and $g>m/2$). The remaining g column districts still vote 100% for the Majoricrats, so we have the reverse ratio as required.

There is no solution when $m\ge2g$, because that majority is too large to overcome by Gerrymandering.

> Start with any solution to the puzzle. The Gerrymandered districts are in a ratio of $m:g$ where the $m$ districts have more than 50% votes for the Gerrymandericans. The proportion of the population that voted for the Gerrymandericans must then be at least $0.5*m/(m+g)$. However this proportion is known to be $g/(m+g)$ of the population. So $g>0.5*m$, or $2g>m$.

Comment: It can be easily noted this smaller simpler map is the minimum solution possible. You require at least 3 people grouped together and as 1:2 does not work as proven, 2:3 is the minimum, which then gives 5 groups and 15 members.

Comment: If you don't post a diagram of the asymptote, Jaap Scherphuis, i might. It's boringly simple enough to be beautiful. (A surplus bounty, for what it's worth, is on the way regardless.)

Comment: @humn: I'm not sure what you mean by asymptote, but I have added a picture of the general solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I found the same results as @Jaap and here is one of the possible results for a 7x7 grid

> The proportions are 4:3 (28 m and 21 g)
>
> ```
>             m m m m m m m
>             g g m g m m m
>             g g g m m m m
>             g g g m m m m
>             g g g g m m m
>             g g g g m m m
>             g g g g m m m
> ```
>
> Splitting into rows and columns give respectively a 4:3 and a 3:4 ratio

I found a way to create all the odd side squares (except 3x3):

> The proportions are n:n+1 (g:m)
>
>  1. Create an array of (2n + 1) x (2n + 1) (starting at 0)
>  2. Fill the cells from (0; 0) to (n; n-1) with "g"
>  3. Fill the cells from (0, n) to (n-1, 2n-1) with "g"
>  4. Take the cell (n-1, 2n-1) and shift it one step to the right
>  5. Fill empty cells with "m"
>
>  Splitting into rows and columns give respectively a n+1:n and a n:n+1 ratio
>
>  Exemple with 5x5 :
>
>  1.
>  (each x represents an empty cell)
>
> ```
>             x x x x x
>             x x x x x
>             x x x x x
>             x x x x x
>             x x x x x
> ```
>
> 2.
>
> ```
>             x x x x x
>             x x x x x
>             x x x x x
>             g g g x x
>             g g g x x
> ```
>
> 3.
>
> ```
>             x x x x x
>             g g x x x
>             g g x x x
>             g g g x x
>             g g g x x
> ```
>
> 4.
>
> ```
>             x x x x x
>             g x g x x
>             g g x x x
>             g g g x x
>             g g g x x
> ```
>
> 5.
>
> ```
>             m m m m m
>             g m g m m
>             g g m m m
>             g g g m m
>             g g g m m
> ```
>
> Finished !

Answer (score 2):

> Let the rectangle's dimensions be $a$ x $b$, the number of Majoricrats be $m$ and Gerrymandericans $g$. Therefore, $ab = m+g$. If $m>g$: 
>  Majoricrats represent $bm/(g+m)=bm/ab=m/a$ rows and $ag/(g+m)=ag/ab=g/b$ columns while Gerrymandericans represent $bg/(g+m)=bg/ab=g/a$ rows and $am/(g+m)=am/ab=m/b$ columns. Both $m$ and $g$ are divisible by $a$ and $b$, but not $ab$ because $ab = m+g$. That means $a$ and $b$ can't be co-primes. Letting $gcd(a,b)=n$, $a=fn$ and $b=hn$, $lcm(a,b)$ will be $fhn$. If $m=xfhn$ and $g=yfhn$, $(x+y)fhn=fhn^2 => x+y = n$. Majoricrats represent $m/a = xfhn/fn = xh$ rows and $g/b = yfhn/hn = yf$ columns while Gerrymandericans represent $g/a = yfhn/fn = yh$ rows and $m/b = xfhn/hn = xf$ columns. Since $m=xfhn$, let's pack some Majoricrats into $yf$ columns, which makes $yfhn$ Majoricrats. The remaining $(x-y)fhn$ Majoricrats must not create any majorities in the remaining $xf$ columns. If there are more than $xfnh/2$ Majoricrats left, they'll keep creating majorities, so $x-y<=x/2$, meaning $y>=x/2$. 
>  ____xf____|____yf____ 
> |..................|...................| 
>  |..................|...................xh 
>  |_________|__________|_ 
> |..................|....................| 
>  |..................|...................yh 
>  |_________|__________| 
>  Now, let's fill both inner rectangles on the right in the shape above with $m$ ($yfnh$ Majoricrats). There are $(x-y)fnh$ Majoricrats left, so every row in the upper-left rectangle must have more than $f(x-y)/2$ Majoricrats, and every column must have fewer than $h(x+y)/2$. If we place $[f(x-y)/2]+1$ Majoricrats on each row, we'll still have some left over. Since $(x-y)fnh/x^2fh=(x-y)n/x^2=(x^2-y^2)/x^2<3/4$, we can place more or less $3xf/4$ Majoricrats on each row such that $floor(3xh/4)$ of them will populate each column. 
>  Let's compare $(x-y)fnh$ to $(3xh-4)xf/4$. 
>  $(x-y)fnh = xfnh-yfnh = x^2fh+y^2fh-2xyfh$ 
>  $(3xh-4)xf/4 = (3x^2hf-4xf)/4$ 
>  Arrange both results: 
>  $4x^2fh+4y^2fh-8xyfh$... **~**... $3x^2hf-4xf$ 
>  $x^2fh+4y^2fh-8xyfh$... **~**... $-4xf$ 
>  $x^2h+4y^2h-8xyh$... **~**... $-4x$ 
>  $h(x^2+4y^2-8xy)$... **~**... $-4x$ 
>  Let $x$ be $ky$: 
>  $h(k^2y^2+4y^2-8ky^2)$... **~**... $-4ky$ 
>  $h(k^2y+4y-8ky)$... **~**... $-4k$ 
>  $hy(k^2+4-8k)$... **~**... $-4k$ 
>  $y>1$, otherwise $x$ would have equalled $2y$ or more. Both sides are negative, so even when we let $y$ be $2$, the left side is smaller, which carries over to the very first equation. Excess Majoricrats can be erased back with the conditions still met because if we placed $[f(x-y)/2]+1$ Majoricrats on each row, we'd still have some left over.

Example:

> $x=3, y=2, f=2, h=1$: 
>  GGMMMM|MMMM 
>  MMMGGG|MMMM 
>  GGGMMM|MMMM 
> ----------------------- 
> GGGGGG|MMMM 
>  GGGGGG|MMMM